# Android Multi-Layered Master/Detail Flow

Tags: android

I would appreciate some Android UI advice (or examples) on the following scenario:

I need to have an activity which follows the Android Master/Detail Flow UI pattern but have it 3 layers deep. I.e. Master A will have a list. On the Detail view of A I will have another list (in detail A) which is essentially the Master for Detail B. Then in Detail B I want another List which is the Master for Detail C. Finally Detail C will contain a list and this is the end of the flow.

To recap:

1. Master A List has Detail A which contains Master B List
2. Master B List points to Detail B which contains Master C List
3. Master C List points to Detail C which contains a List.

Any advice you can offer on how this can be implemented would be much appreciated. So far I have only implemented a standard Master Detail Flow with one Master and one Detail Screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new Master Detail project, you will see in the layout folder that the `activity_item_twopane.xml` is composed of a Fragment (the list) and a Framelayout (the detail).

The `fragment_item_detail.xml` is just a text, what you could do is to change the `framgment_item_detail.xml` to a layout composed of a `Fragment` and a `FrameLayout`, so you would have the same behavior as the main activity. It's a start...

BR,
Alexandre.